# Set file-change based conflict resolution decision making

Tags: git

When I am resolving conflicts in code -
how can I do :
"for all the files that have not changed since i raised this PR" - I want to retain my current changes - resolve only for files which have actually changed since the Pr was raised

Comment: What you ask for is what a merge does automatically and where you do *not* get a conflict anyway. You (can) get a conflict only when both your branch and upstream have changed the same file. So, it is unclear what you want.